# Прикрепить изображения к посту

Tags: ios, изображения, ui, uicollectionview

Делаю POST-отправку данных (создание записи), в записи создается заголовок, описание и есть возможность прикрепить картинки.

Я думаю, нужно прикрепить как-то `UICollectionView` и кнопку <kbd>+</kbd>, и при нажатии на нее добавлять новую ячейку, но как в ней создать какой-нибудь крестик для отмены? возможно ли это?

Или это нужно создавать какой-нибудь `UIScrollView`? Нет ли проектов с открытым кодом, чтобы посмотреть пример?

Comment: объясните подробно, что вам надо сделать и как оно должно выглядеть

Comment: Примерно как в социальных сетях vk или facebook - возможность прикрепить несколько изображений к посту. Не понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретного дизайна. Вопрос очень размытый, попробуйте конкретизировать. Ну или покажите пример экрана, который должен получиться, чтобы можно было обсудить как это лучше сделать. Ответ на вопрос "возможно ли это" всегда будет "да, возможно".